# How to get user data Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Android development. I need to put and get information through Firebase. I managed to make the assignment of information, but I can not make getting information from the database.

```
test_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String user_id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
            DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user_id);

            String testData = edit_data_FB.getText().toString();

            Map newPost = new HashMap();
            newPost.put("testData",testData);

            current_user_db.setValue(newPost);
        }
    });

    test_get.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String user_id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
            DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user_id).child("testData").val;

            //Map newPost = new HashMap();
            //String data = newPost.get();

            //text_get.setText();
        }
    });
```

Mission database has the following form
[Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3guk.png) I need to get the testData value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve `testData` try the following:

```
String user_id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user_id);
current_user_db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    String testData = dataSnapshot.child("testData").getValue(String.class);
 }

 @Override
 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Attach a listener to your reference and then you will be able to retrieve `testData`